# How to overlap two Views which are located one below another?

Tags: android

I have two `View`s which reside one below another and I need to slightly overlap their edges so the bottom one was slightly under the top one.

Comment: use a relative layout

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html. Check layerList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `marginTop`  and set to -dp

```
           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/1"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative `layout_margin`.